# How to define a static Home page

Tags: customization

I am trying to create a web site with a static "home" page. But when I follow the "very clear instructions" and create a Home page I end up with two Home pages. But only one is listed in the pages to edit. When I delete that I have no Home page left that I can edit and make static.

And I would prefer not to have the title "Home" on my home page. So I'm missing something, like how to edit the default home page.

I have made web sites before (at EarthLink and then Comcast) and never had the extreme difficulty and behavior that does not follow the instructions as at WordPress! My initial experience is quite negative. You can't spend huge amounts of time just guessing and WordPress gives like no support to get started.

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly because a static link saying Home was added to the menu and then you created another page called home which also showed up in the menu.

First let's take care of the static home page setting (if you haven't got that set already)
Under `Settings` and then `Reading` you'll have the option to select a static page as the homepage and another page as your blog page. If you don't want a blog yet, then just don't select a page.

Next let's set that menu right. 
Under `Appearances` you'll find `Menu` you might have to create a menu then add and sort the page you want, once done check the option to make this the `Primary` menu and hit save.

Comment: Thank you Alexander. However this only partially solves the problem. There is no way to sort the entries on the menu. Is there a way I can zero out the web site (but keep the URL) and then start over and not create a new Home page? I would like to get rid of the extra Home page and make the default page the "Front" page.

Comment: Menu items added can be moved up and down, it UI is drag and drop.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great resource that will explain to you how templating works. http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Template_Files Hope this gives you insight.

[image: What I know is you should be able to set one static page as your homepage from Customize menu in your dashboard.]